# Auto Generate php pages from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, vs-web-site-project

I currently have a website where i am pulling information from a database and uploading to the web database.

What im having trouble with is generating pages based on that information.

My question is, is it possible to generate pages in php?

If so how would i go about doing so the information is the machine name, job its running quantity.

What im trying to do is using that information to generate a page on the machine names and either an auto refresh for that information or sliding through each new generated page to display data on a screen.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated:)!

Comment: You realize that the **MAJOR** use of PHP is to talk to a database, suck out data, and present that data as a web page? You might as well ask "is a hammer used to pound in nails?"

Comment: _is it possible to generate pages in php?_ Really? Browse a few questions tagged PHP.

Comment: yes i do realize that, all i'm trying to do is generate the page and call the information from the database and display php. if there is another language (js,html etc) that has the function to generate a page and then display the use or use php to display the information then thats fine, my main goal is to generate the page based on the name then display all the data relevant to that name

Comment: @MikeW im sorry im new to web building with PHP and i have looked but am unable anything that answers my question

Comment: You basically want to store HTML tags inside a database and if a page has a certain create a html page based on them tags?

Comment: what i want to do is pull the information from the database and display it on a new page automatically without physically creating the html pages individually as we have machines come in and out constantly. So if a new machine came in it would see the new name create the page then display the data relevant to the new machine

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you need to write html to display information on the web page

Comment: thanks, i wasnt too sure but i just wanted to confirm as im new to php, so would it be possible to use say a html template and then generate a new page in another language then have that page populated via the php?

Comment: Yeah, you could write a C#/Java whatever application which generate tags for you and generates your own HTML page for you, that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to store HTML tags inside a database and if a page has a certain create a html page based on them tags? – Sythnet 13 mins ago

what i want to do is pull the information from the database and display it on a new page automatically without physically creating the html pages individually as we have machines come in and out constantly. So if a new machine came in it would see the new name create the page then display the data relevant to the new machine – RipperStatic 10 mins ago
I don't think that is possible, you need to write html to display information on the web page – Sythnet 7 mins ago

thanks, i wasnt too sure but i just wanted to confirm as im new to php, so would it be possible to use say a html template and then generate a new page in another language then have that page populated via the php? – RipperStatic 5 mins ago
Yeah, you could write a C#/Java whatever application which generate tags for you and generates your own HTML page for you, that is possible. – Sythnet 2 mins ago edit

okay thanks will look into that :) – RipperStatic 2 mins ago

Since I guess the answer has been solved in a way or (redirected), I'm going to post the conversation as the answer.

Comment: I'm just worried he took `you could write a C#/Java whatever application` to mean C# and Java are the solution to his specific problem.